# My input html forms misses focus/empties when a Var changes

Tags: dom, data-binding, scala.js, lost-focus, binding.scala

I want to create some UI from Binding.scala. The UI contains a textbox. When the user type text in the textbox, I want to change the background color according to the user input.

```
import com.thoughtworks.binding._, Binding._
import org.scalajs.dom._

@dom def render = {
  val color = Var("")
  val styleText: String = s"background-color: ${color.bind}"

  // <div> and <input> will be recreated once data changes.
  <div style={styleText}>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" oninput={ _: Any => color := myInput.value }/>
  </div>
}

dom.render(document.body, render)
```

The example runs on [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/NtIcJYY/1).

However, when I enter something in the textbox, the textbox misses focus and still keep empty.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you defined the `<input ...>` and `.bind` in the same `@dom` method and the `<input ...>` is after `.bind`. Try to refactor the `.bind` and `<input ...>` into separate `@dom` methods or let the `.bind` expression nested in another DOM.

---

For example, if `myInput` is written before `.bind`, it will not be recreated:

```
import com.thoughtworks.binding._, Binding._
import org.scalajs.dom._

@dom def render = {
  val color = Var("")
  val myInput = <input id="myInput" type="text" oninput={ _: Any => color := myInput.value }/>
  val styleText: String = s"background-color: ${color.bind}"

  // <div> will be recreated once data changes.
  // <input> will not be recreated.
  <div style={styleText}>
    {myInput}
  </div>
}

dom.render(document.body, render)
```

The above example runs on [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/OIkvkbf/2).

---

If the `.bind` expression is embedded in a XHTML literal, it will not affect its children:

```
import com.thoughtworks.binding._, Binding._
import org.scalajs.dom._

@dom def render = {
  val color = Var("")

  // <div> and <input> will not be recreated when data changes.
  // Only the class attribute will be changed.
  <div style={s"background-color: ${color.bind}"}>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" oninput={ _: Any => color := myInput.value }/>
  </div>
}

dom.render(document.body, render)
```

The above example runs on [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/1KOau6C/3).

---

Another approach is wrapping `.bind` expression in a `@dom val`:

```
import com.thoughtworks.binding._, Binding._
import org.scalajs.dom._

@dom def render = {
  val color = Var("")
  @dom val styleText: Binding[String] = s"background-color: ${color.bind}"

  // <div> and <input> will not be recreated when data changes.
  // Only the class attribute will be changed.
  <div style={styleText.bind}>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" oninput={ _: Any => color := myInput.value }/>
  </div>
}

dom.render(document.body, render)
```

The above example runs on [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/hU9xfbQ/2).

Comment: This question and answer is moved from https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala/wiki/FAQ